# Give the message to the user while running the job

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-cdt, jobs

I have a method `buildTargets()` which is called when the user clicks on one of the UI menu operations.

```java
static public void buildTargets(Shell shell, final IMakeTarget[] targets) {
        saveAllResources(targets);
        Job targetJob = new Job(MakeUIPlugin.getResourceString("TargetBuild.backgroundTask.name")) { //$NON-NLS-1$
            @Override
            protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor monitor) {
                monitor.beginTask(MakeUIPlugin.getResourceString("TargetBuild.monitor.beginTask"), targets.length); //$NON-NLS-1$
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
                        final IMakeTarget target = targets[i];
                        IWorkspaceRunnable runnable = new IWorkspaceRunnable() {

                            public void run(IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
                                target.build(new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));                               
                            }
                        };

                        MakeUIPlugin.getWorkspace().run(runnable, null, IResource.NONE, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 1));
                    }
                } catch (CoreException e) {
                    return e.getStatus();
                } catch (OperationCanceledException e) {
                } finally {
                    monitor.done();
                }
                return Status.OK_STATUS;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean belongsTo(Object family) {
                return ResourcesPlugin.FAMILY_MANUAL_BUILD == family;
            }           
        };

        // workaround for bug 270326, initialize CUIPlugin preference store to avoid race condition
        CUIPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().getString("dummy"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        targetJob.schedule();

    }
}
```

When the user clicks again the same kind of operation, it simply ignores the second request while running the first operation. It's my requirement and I think the `IWorkspace.run()` method is doing this (as far as I understand). The second operation is executing all the code but the `IWorkspace.run()` method.

I have tried adding a listener.

```java
targetJob.addJobChangeListener(new JobChangeAdapter() {
public void done(IJobChangeEvent event) {
    if (event.getResult().isOK())
       System.out.println("Job completed successfully");
    else
       System.out.println("Job did not complete successfully");
    }
 });

targetJob.setSystem(true);
```

But when I click the menu operation the second time while running the first job, my `execute()` method of handler still calls `buildTargets()` and executes all the code without running  the `IWorkspace.run()` method. My console prints end s.o.p. "Job completed successfully" for second click onwards.

So, If a user clicks the same operation second time onwards, I want to give a message to the user saying wait for the previous job to complete. How do I know the status of the first job running, so that I can give the message? I think I need to decide before creating the new job in `buildTargets()` method?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock` to solve my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you create the `Job` you can add an `IJobChangeListener` to be notified about the status of the job:

```java
targetJob.addJobChangeListener(listener);
```

The listener has a `done` method that is called when the job finishes.

You will need to maintain a 'job active' flag set when the job is scheduled and cleared by the job change listener 'done' method. The menu handler will have to check this flag.

Comment: Hi greg, thank you for quick response. Colud you please check my updated question?

Comment: You need to have a job active flag to test - added to answer